# Why can't I navigate to /.ssh folder on jailbroken iPhone 5S

Tags: iphone, terminal, jailbreak, ssh

I have installed OpenSSH on my jailbroken iPhone 5S, I am trying to set up ssh keys for it but I need to get to my /.ssh folder. I try to cd there while at root with cd ~/.ssh but it says "not a directory". I then tried mkdir ~/.ssh and get "cannot make directory: file exists". So once again I tried to cd ~/.ssh and still nada. I navigated to ~ and ls, and once again no .ssh directory.

```
$ ls -ad ~/.ssh
/var/root/.ssh
$ echo ~
/var/root
```

Comment: `.ssh` seems to be a file, not a directory. Can you add the output of `ls -ad ~/.ssh` and `echo ~` to your question?

Comment: youre right it is indeed a file

Comment: the directory didnt get created when I copied my key using scp it instead created .ssh as a file. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `.ssh` is a file and not a directory. Either remove the file (`rm ~/.ssh`) or rename it (`mv ~/.ssh ~/.ssh-strange`) and set up your ssh keys again.